# Formatting a number as hexadecimal using MessageFormat in Java

Tags: java, hex, messageformat

How do I use `MessageFormat` to format a number in hexadecimal? I have an existing `MessageFormat` pattern, and the customer wants to change it from a decimal number to a three-digit hex number. Is this possible using `MessageFormat`? Or do I have to switch to a more powerful formatter? Or some other trick?

Comment: I would use Integer.toHexString() and format the string.  You could have a more powerful MessageFormatter by writing your own.

Comment: Instead of providing a number, provides an hexadecimal String of that number, and stick to MessageFormat. Possibly provide both options with different indexes for better flexibility.

Comment: This might do what you want. It's a pluggable ExtendedMessageFormat (extends MessageFormat) https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/ExtendedMessageFormat.html

Comment: `MessageFormat` does not support it in the pattern level.

Comment: An example using ExtendedMessageFormat https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/commons-lang/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/ExtendedMessageFormatTest.java.shtml

Comment: @NikhilJain This is not a duplicate. This question is specifically about `MessageFormat`.